# Send Id to proxy.config.json dynamically in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-services, http-proxy

I am unable to send "id" in following scenario.
Ex: url=`somedomain/{id}/emp`
For this I set the url in proxy.config.json file as

```
"/employee": {
  "target":"somedomain",
  "secure":false,
  "pathReWrite: {
    "/employee":""
  }
}
```

Now in the Angular Service file I am calling as

```
this.http.post(`http://localhost:4200/employee/{id}/emp`);
```

in this case the total url is replaced with /employee only. But I want to send "id" dynamically through proxy.config.js file. Could you please help me out how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a typo.

Replace capital `W` with `w` in `pathReWrite`:

```
   should be w
       \/
"pathReWrite: {
  "/employee":""
}
```

Comment: I tried with that too.. It’s not working with dynamic id

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic id? If you send `/employee/3/emp` it will rewrite to `somedomain/3/emp`, `/employee/9/emp` => `/somedomain/9/emp` etc

Comment: But it’s rewriting the total url from angular service. If I give id in the url, its replacing with proxy config url.. btw I am appending  id in service to url like proxy url + id.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you're combining url